# Using formatting on a string, which has a '%' sign already

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a `string`, which stores my SQL code, and it looks like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField LIKE '%2015' AND myOtherField = %d'
```

**First question:** How can I use [formatting](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Format) on `myOtherField` only? The code below does not seem to ignore the first % sign:

```
MyQuery.SQL.Add(Format(myString, myNumber));
```

**Second question:** How can I use formatting, when I need the first '%' sign for my SQL, but I want to format the date, too? Sadly, the following code does not work either.

```
'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField LIKE '%%d' AND myOtherField = %d'
```

Comment: Stop doing this and use parameters. You are safe here, but you are a short step away from SQL injection

Comment: As for `Format`, the answer to your question can be found in the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.Format

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not to mention that parameterized queries are simply more performant, often significantly so.

Comment: We definitely need a "don't do this!" flag on stack overflow. This is a legitimate but wrong question - don't use string composition for possibly tainted values in SQL (I know %d is mostly safe, but the pattern is still problematic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an extra % before the % sign you want to keep

Like this:

```
  Caption := Format('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField LIKE ''%%2015'' AND myOtherField = %d', [4711]);
```

And same solution to question 2:

```
  Caption := Format('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField LIKE ''%%%d'' AND myOtherField = %d', [4711, 4712]);
```

Comment: @Martyn Compare the string here, and that in the code, they are different

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, I know, I was just meaning that the OP had obviously already tried %% (but presumably had tripped over not escaping the quotes).

Comment: In my second code I was describing, that there is a '%' already, and the code is what I have tried to use, but did not work. This is the answer I was looking for, adding an extra % solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @JensBorrisholt I will, but I have to wait one more minute. :)

Comment: @ReyesJ.  I agree you should accept this answer since it directly and correctly answers the question you asked.  As others have noted, however, please take away from this that the above, although it now *works*, is still the *wrong* way to build an SQL query.  Hugh's answer demonstrates the use of parameters to build a query - this is how you should actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
MyQuery.Sql.BeginUpdate;
MyQuery.Sql.Add('SELECT * FROM myTable');
MyQuery.Sql.Add('WHERE myField LIKE :MyField AND');
MyQuery.Sql.Add('myOtherField = :MyOtherField');
MyQuery.Sql.EndUpdate;

MyQuery.Parameters[0].Value := '%' + '2015';
MyQuery.Parameters[1].Value := intval;
```

I suggest this should be the boilerplate solution for all your queries; it requires very little extra effort to do and is more readable than fiddling with quotes and escape characters.

That is not to say the accepted answer is wrong, given the question.

Comment: Alternatively, too, you can index your parameters by name.  This is useful if you change the query later and the order of the parameters changes.  ie: `MyQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('MyField').Value := '%2015'`

Comment: J... is correct - `ParamByName` is particularly common when the sql string is separate from the code that is setting the parameter values.  There is a small performance hit but it is safer.

Comment: Indeed, it can depend on the use case.  I would code for clarity and maintanability first until performance becomes an issue, generally.

Comment: @J... I am not sure I 100% agree with the addition of `BeginUpdate` `EndUpdate` in your edit.  Does that not obfuscate the point a little?

Comment: Why not just do a direct assignment to MyQuery.Sql.Text instead of the .Add()s?

Comment: @MartynA The `Add` method passes by reference - it saves copying and rebuilding intermediate strings, memory allocation, etc.

Comment: @J...I suppose, but I've lost track of the number of times I've seen qs where the OP has constructed a Sql statement which contained syntatic or semantic error that weren't obvious because of Add()ing to the Sql in installments, as it were, whereas if they'd constructed a single string in the first place they could probably have spotted the error in the IDE evaluator themselves.

Comment: @MartynA You can always add a watch on the `.Text` property... I find it cleaner than a sprawling concatenation, personally.

Comment: My (unedited) answer set Sql.Text in one go.  The point that I was trying to make was that parameters are easy to use.  The `BeginUpdate` .. `Endupdate` with `Add()` looks more complex to my eye.

Comment: @HughJones Yes, but you're also suggesting to use this as boilerplate and, if you're going to do that, then you might as well make everything right, no?